# Can't pan around my OpenLayers map .. unless there are no Layers under the mouse

Tags: openlayers-2

So I've got my map displayed and some `Features` added to a `Layer`. All good, etc.

When I try and pan around my map, I can only pan when I left-click the mouse .. hold .. and drag the mouse ... when the mouse cursor is NOT over a feature/shape on the vector layer.

Otherwise, the panning works great.

What's the trick to say .. can pan the map at any time / anywhere the mouse cursor is?

Comment: did you add any control to your map for your features?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on the main site few years ago.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122160/mouse-drag-on-kml-features-with-openlayers

And in some respects in the OL documentation as well:

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SelectFeatureControlMapDragIssues